# Blazor Server Net 7 PageTitle with HeadOutlet do not add <title> tag in <head>

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app.

In my _Host.cshtml I have following row:

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

On my Blazor page:

```
<PageTitle>Login Title</PageTitle>
```

When I run the project I can see the title text when I hover mouse on browser tab.

[image]

However, when I open html source in the browser, there is no  tag.

[image]

Any help appreciated

Comment: What help do you want - this is how it works

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it. I thought it must place <title> tag with the title, specified on <PageTitle>. What If i need content of <PageTitle> to be rendered in <title> tag on each page?

Comment: The title is added dynamically at runtime - viewing the page source shows you the static content that was loaded from the server. You can use `<PageTitle>` on each page to set the different values

Comment: I'm bothering about Search Engines optimization. The title you suggest to use is good for users. They will see it in the browser tab. But Search Engines want to see <title> in the static html.

Comment: @MisterMagoo : the headoutlet is ServerPrerendered. The tag should be there. (And it is).

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't spotted that it was prerendering, thanks

Comment: There is not title tag. outlet is set to server prerendered. No title word in html source of the page. And no in the part generated by the outlet. And this is strange

Answer (score 1):

Just scroll to the right...  Way to the right.

The `<title>` tag is there, After that very long `<!--Blazor: .... -->` comment.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm searching for "title" in the file. There is no need to scroll it. No word title is present in file. And yes, I think it must be there.

Comment: If I create default blazor app, there is a title tag generated with the outlet. The problem is to understand. What else can be reason of missing title. What was changed or not present for it to appear

Comment: It's true in a new blazor server app from scratch the index page shows the headoutlet output on the head section (hidden after that very long comment). But my blazor server app does not. Did you find a reason?